# 'Newest' tab not showing newest question while 'Active' does

Tags: bug, tags, tabs

I came across [a new JQ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882165/append-list-just-before-the-closing-braces-of-json-file) which was asked just now.

When going to the tag in question; [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), the [Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq?tab=Newest) tab (still) does not show the new question, were as the [Active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882165/append-list-just-before-the-closing-braces-of-json-file) does show the question.

- [Screenshot of Active tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LGBI.png)
- [Screenshot of Newest tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW0wR.png)

---

###### **Why is the new question not shown on the 'Newest' tab?**

Comment: Caching? After 14 minutes? Server side? How is this normal? Still not listed in 'Newest'.....

Comment: I don't think this is caching issue. I'm viewing the PHP tag. I'm getting the push question updates, but if I refresh the page, the last question was an hour ago, and those pushed questions disappear.

Comment: Also viewing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php in an incognito browser, the last question was an hour ago.

Comment: Yea I still have the same issue. Think this has been closes to quickly,,,

Comment: Whatever it was seems to have been fixed. Refreshing brings up the new questions again for me.

Comment: This is something I see happening from time to time too, so a valid question to be asked IMHO.